# Problems export and importing a library of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following data definiton files:

Circle.js

```
export default {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    radius: 35
}
```

Line.js

```
export default {
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 0,
    y2: 0
}
```

A library of shapes (`shapeslib`):

```
import Circle from "./Circle";
import Line from "./Line";

const shapes = {
    Circle ,
    Line
};


export const getShape = name => {
    if (!shapes[name]) throw new Error("(getShape) Cannot retrieve shape " + name);

    return shapes[name];
};
```

At the main program, I want to use them:

```
import { getShape } from "../shapeslib";

const GetData = () => {

    let circle = getShape("Circle"); << Returning error (Cannot retrieve shape Circle)
    let line = getShape("Line");

    console.log("The circle radius is " + circle.radius);
    console.log("The line X1 is " + line.x1);
}
```

I'm getting error when trying to get the shape object (showed in main code)...

How can I make the `getShape` function to work properly?

Comment: Why not import the shapes directly in the main program?

Comment: Can’t. I really need the library...

Comment: `Cicle` typo.... fix that, and it works https://jsfiddle.net/uqbserck/

Comment: No, you've changed the code and removed the import/export issue... Pay attention to the post title - my problem is related to import/export, not to Javascript object. I need to make it work using export/import. This is a proto of a big library that needs to be accessed using `getShape`, where every shape has a unique file.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. It just works - https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cori-bp4wh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark